# Tefillin shel yad- the first knot

Tags: tefilin

I have a crimp in the first knot of my tfillin shel yad, the one directly on my upper tricep, the leather has bended into a crimp.

I don’t see how to avoid this crimp. For the tfillin we are tightening a circle around a horizontal plane, it seems impossible that the plane would not bend in.

Does this create kosher issues?

Comment: 1:32 of this Aish video. The leather strap changes direction. How can you keep a crimp or a bend from a strap when you change its direction. Seems like a basic 3-d math problem that you can’t. https://youtu.be/uezimCF8JDg

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are asking but either this is a duplicate or it's unclear (or it's seeking personal psak that we can't provide). In any event, regarding your own tefillin you should show them to a sofer when you can since even most regular rabbis won't be sure how to answer your question.